# invalid property is always false in first render, react hook form 7

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I am developing a wizard setup for the company I work for, this wizard will be used for the sign in flow when a user try to create an account.

For each step I conditionally render different inputs, when the input or inputs of the actual step of the setup are valid, the user can go to the next step.

To achieve this, I need to know if the **invalid** property of the inputs or input in the current page is false, to achieve this I am using react hook form ^7.43.9 and **getFieldState** of the **useForm** hook.

The problem is that the **invalid** property is always **false** in first render, it has to be **true** at first render.

I simplified the code for you, this code only checks if **firstName.invalid** (line:15) is false, if it is false, the user can continue, if not, the user has to try again.

The validation for **firstName** is min 3 chars and it is required, if you click the button with no value, you are able to go to the next step, and this is wrong because validation rules are never applied.

Is there any way to make **invalid** true in first render?

Is there another way to know if the current inputs are valid?

Here is the code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const [step, setstep] = useState(1);
  const {
    register,
    getFieldState,
    // I subscribed to errors as the documentation says
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onChange",
  });

  const handleStep = () => {
    const firstName = getFieldState("firstName");
    if (firstName.invalid) {
      alert("oh no, invalid is true, so try again");
    } else {
      alert("excelente, invalid is false, so you can go next step");
    }
  };

  return (
    <form style={{ padding: "1rem" }}>
      <h1>Step 1</h1>
      <input {...register("firstName", { required: true, min: 3 })} />
      <button type="button" onClick={() => handleStep()}>
        Continue
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

You can try it on codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-jennings-vbz1vf?file=/src/App.tsx

This is the link to the documentarion about how to use **getFieldState**

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/getfieldstate/

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to essentially validate your form values on the component mounting.

I that case you can use the [trigger function](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/trigger/) provided by `useForm`. And then call that upon the component mounting using the `useEffect` lifecycle hook.

You solution would look something like this:

```
const {
  register,
  getFieldState,
  formState: { errors },
  trigger // add this variable
} = useForm({
  mode: "onChange",
});

useEffect(() => {
  trigger(); // triggers all form validations when component is mounted
}, [])
```

**Additional Issue**

Including the answer @adsy mentioned here as well because this is a separate bug you're also facing.

You should do:

```
<input {...register("firstName", { required: true, minLength: 3 })} />
```

Because `min` refers to a numeric minimum, but you're talking about string length, so `minLength` should be used here.

Comment: Thank you, the answer is a combination between your answer and the adsy's answer

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've updated my answer accordingly to take that into account.

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant

```
<input {...register("firstName", { required: true, minLength: 3 })} />
```

I.e. `minLength` and *not* `min`. Which is about numerical values.

Comment: Thank you, the answer is a combination between your answer and Barry's answer

Comment: I didn't notice I wrote min instead of minLength, logic errors can be difficult to notice